# Dynamically setting request headers for REST request using Postman Interceptor

Tags: header, postman, interceptor

Is it possible to dynamically (automatically) set request headers for REST request using Postman Interceptor?  We are currently setting multiple headers for each new request in a collection manually, we'd like to automate this if possible.  How to achieve and please provide an example?  thanks in advance.

p.s. I am not talking about writing a pre-request script unless we can write a global script that will be automatically used when we create each new request.  The solution needs to be fully automated so we don't need to manually write the header key/value pairs for each new request.  The key names will be the same each request and the values will be the same as well (environment variables).

using v4.10.7 of Postman for Mac.